# Terraform: How do I use for_each over a comma-delimited string in a dynamic block?

Tags: terraform, azure-functions

I am writing an Azure Function app module which is causing me some trouble. I want to add multiple ip_restriction blocks using a for_each, iterating over a comma-delimited string, but I'm missing out on something here.

Given the following block (with random IP CIDR blocks)

```
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "this" {
...
    dynamic "ip_restriction" {
      for_each         = split(",", "1.2.3.4/28,2.3.4.5/28")
      content {
        ip_address = {          

          ip_address    = ip_restriction.value
        }
      }
    }  
...
```

I get the following error:

`Inappropriate value for attribute "ip_address": string required`

I get the error twice which tells me that the iterator has tried, and failed twice to retrieve the value using '.value'

I've read https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks (of course) and tried various things for a few hours now without being able to figure out why 'value' seems empty.

How do I retrieve the distinct CIDR address if .value isn't the right thing to do?

Comment: Have you tried `toset(split(",", "1.2.3.4/28,2.3.4.5/28"))`?

Comment: Yes, no luck  :o/

Comment: @MarkoE It was a syntax mishap, see below

Comment: Sure, fixed it in my answer as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `for_each` meta-argument accepts a **map or a set of strings**. What you are currently providing is a **list of strings**. If you are not hardcoding the values as in your example, you could create a local variable:

```
locals {
  ip_addresses = split(",", "1.2.3.4/28,2.3.4.5/28")
}
```

Then, in the `dynamic` block, you can use that local variable and cast it to a set with `toset` [1]:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "this" {
...
    dynamic "ip_restriction" {
      for_each         = toset(local.ip_addresses)
      content {
          ip_address    = ip_restriction.value
        }
    }  
...
```

If you do not want to do that, you can do the conversion like this:

```
resource "azurerm_windows_function_app" "this" {
...
    dynamic "ip_restriction" {
      for_each         = toset(split(",", "1.2.3.4/28,2.3.4.5/28"))
      content {
        ip_address    = ip_restriction.value
        }
    }  
...
```

---

[1] https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/functions/toset

Answer (score 1):

Dammit...  A collegue of mine found the error, it was sitting approx. 40 inches from the keyboard  :o)

It was a syntax beef, I had wrapped the "ip_address" block in an "ip_address" block

The correct code is:

```
    dynamic "ip_restriction" {
      for_each  = split(",", var.ip_restriction_allow_ip_range)

      content {
        ip_address  = ip_restriction.value
        name        = "github_largerunner"
      }
    }
```